# Does exist a method to list all jobs in crontab for all users on a system

Tags: linux, fedora, user-management, cron

The title says everything.

I'm using Fedora 11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is **no native command** to do this, but you can use a **simple bash oneliner** like this:

```
for u in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do sudo crontab -u $u -l; done
```

The above would read out all user entries in `/etc/passwd` and list their appropriate crontab entries. `sudo` usage is required, since you'd need superuser privileges to access another user's cron.

Comment: This assumes your users are all listed in /etc/passwd.  If you use a different naming service, say for example LDAP, to define your user namespace, they will not appear in /etc/passwd.  You might instead consider using "getent passwd" in place of the cut command above.

Answer (score 3):

`cat /var/spool/cron/*`

Many distributions have additional system crons configured via /etc as well.  For example, CentOS has files in `/etc/cron*`

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so

You could do something like this:

```
for crontab in `ls /etc/cron.*/* /var/spool/cron/* /etc/crontab`
do
echo $crontab
cat $crontab
done
```